# Bowling Score and Exception Handling

Tags: java, arrays, string, primitive-types

This is a code for calculating the Bowling Score,I need help in fixing this error :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Here is my input(which I store in a text file named bowling.txt).

0 4 5 3 4 2 4 4 3 5 0 8 3 1 2 1 6 4 3 4

0 P 5 3 4 2 4 4 3 5 0 8 3 1 2 1 6 4 3 4

The game has 10 frames,two tries for each frame,so I thought I need 20 numbers(scores) in the text file.

And here is what I get:

```
The score is 66
The score is 77
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at pin.main(pin.java:77)
```

N.B: I would give +1 for all useful answers!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;   
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;   
import java.io.FileReader;    
import java.io.IOException;    

public class pin     
{
    static String tries;    
    public static int value(int index) 
    {    
        int i = 0;
        if (tries.charAt(index) == 'T')
            i = 10;
        else if (tries.charAt(index) == 'P')
            i =10 -(tries.charAt(index-2)-'0');
        else
            i = tries.charAt(index)-'0' ;
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException    
    {
        int score = 0;    
        int frameIndex;    
        int i = 0;    
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Users/PC4599/Desktop/programming/bowling.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        tries = br.readLine();

        while (tries != null) 
        {
            score = 0;
            frameIndex = 0;
            i = 0;
            while (frameIndex != 10) 
            {
                if (tries.charAt(i)=='T') //Strike 
                {
                    score =(score + 10 + value(i + 2) + value(i + 4));
                    i = i + 2;
                } 
                else if (tries.charAt(i+2)=='P') //Spare 
                {
                    score =(score + 10 + value(i + 4));
                    i = i + 4;
                }
                else 
                {
                    score =(score + (tries.charAt(i)-'0') + (tries.charAt(i + 2)-'0'));//Neither Strike nor Spare 
                    i = i + 4;
                }
                frameIndex = frameIndex + 1;

            }

            System.out.println("The score is "+score);
            tries = br.readLine();    
        }    
        br.close();    
        fr.close();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: You actually need 21 numbers as you can throw three times in the tenth frame if you spare/strike it. Also, you should read up [some text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling#Scoring) about scoring, because you get multiplicators for later throws if you have strikes and spares... And you haven't accounted for them yet.

Comment: You are right,I did not take in consideration the case of the "tenth frame,when you have the right to get 3 tries".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `while (tries != null)` loop is running three times. Your input file probably has an extra line at the end, which might just be whitespace.

Given the format of your data input, a minimal correct line of scores would have 23 characters (12 strikes separated by spaces), so you could change that check to something like `while ((tries != null) && (tries.length() >= 23))`. That should solve this problem and seems like a pretty reasonable thing to do anyway. (If I'm not remembering how to score bowling correctly, you can probably make the appropriate adjustments.)

Comment: I would agree with David. It seems that there is an extra '\n' character in there at the end.

Comment: Your answer rocks!,if I have some questions ,I will get back.